# AWS RDS MySQL 5.7 -> 8 warnings

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm doing the 5.7 to 8 upgrade form my MySQL RDS, and I got some warnings and an error:

1. Usage of db objects with names conflicting with new reserved keywords (fixed, renamed the table)
2. Usage of utf8mb3 charset (about to fix, have the script)
3. Usage of removed functions, PROCEDURE uses removed function AREA (consider using ST_AREA instead) fixed, removed the SP and made it an sql string instead, AREA isn't used in the SP so not sure why it freaked out)
4. Creating indexes larger than 767 bytes on tables with redundant row format might cause the tables to be inaccessible.
   You have one or more tables with redundant row format. Creating an index larger than 767 bytes might cause the table to be inaccessible (only 50 tables are shown).

The fix for 4 seems to be to set row_format to "dynaimc".

My question is, can any of these changes cause issues with existing data? I don't think changing the collation will cause issues (have already tried it with a test database), but setting row_format is something I haven't been able to test?

Can changing row_format to dynamic cause issues with existing data?

In addition, I also noticed that I have two empty databases on my RDS, called INNODB and TMP. Anyone know why these have been created, and can they be dropped?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB DYNAMIC row format can store the same data as other row formats. I have never seen a case where changing the row format changed the logical data, it only stores it differently, and this is transparent. Using DYNAMIC increases the maximum size of index you can create (as you noted), and it increases the number of BLOB/TEXT columns you can store in a given table. There's little downside to using DYNAMIC row format, but depending on the table, reversing this change may not be possible.

That said, I don't know your data, so I'm not offering a guarantee. If you are in doubt, I suggest you test the operation on a copy of your database.

Regarding changing the character set, I assume you're changing from utf8mb3 to utf8mb4. The latter is a superset of the former. All characters in utf8mb3 are the same in utf8mb4.

Remember to use `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET...`, which converts each column's character set. Only changing the table's default character set doesn't change the existing columns of that table.

Collation doesn't affect character encoding. It only affects how those characters are compared or sorted.

I don't know about the extra schemas `INNODB` and `TMP`. No schemas of those names exist on my local instance of MySQL 8.3.0. If these are part of a value-add feature of AWS RDS, I don't know about it. If they are empty, then they are doing no harm, and not costing you anything in storage costs. I would not drop them until you learn their purpose. Try asking AWS support.